# How to subtract one value in a column from the value in previous row in another column in same table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If Activity at is not null, then I need to subtract 
Action at(next value of the Activity at)-Activity at

Activity at is Null then Null
Both Activity and Action are Null then Null

Example -

```
ClassId StudentId CardId Card Time Id   Activity at Action at
332     5299      27305  204070         2019-09-09  
332     5299      27305  204073                     2019-09-09
332     5299      27305  206632         2019-09-12 
332     5299      27305  206636                     2019-09-12
332     5299      27305  206637     
332     5299      27305  206640                     2019-09-12
```

Desired Result -

```
Cart Time Id    Difference
204070      0.017094907
204073      Null
206632      0.00380787
206636      Null
206637      Null
206640      Null
```

Comment: How is `0.017094907` calculated???

Comment: Yes I have calculated manually

For Card time Id 204070, Activity at is not null 
so for 204070 Action at -Activity at = 0.017

Comment: Please show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Sample database (using something like sqlfiddle) would be appreciated

Comment: I did it manually in excel but now I need to do it in SQL

Comment: So show your arithmetic

Comment: `Activity at` `Action at` both are `datetime` or `date` ??